# Creating a Database Catalog For Our Network

Tags: sql, sql-server

The final product of this project is to create a Database Catalog for all of our servers. It needs to be dynamic, so that as we change names and locations of the servers we can still report on them. In general, we want to have a table created that contains the Server Name, Database Name, Table Name, and Column Name. From there I will use Report Designer to display the results the way the executives want it.

My idea is to use an Excel worksheet as the list of Server Names. From there I should be able to query all the rest of the information. In the code below, I am just going to populate the Server Names manually.

Right now my code will get me the first row of information: First Server Name, First Database Name, First Table Name, First Column Name. What I need it to do next is to create a row for each of the column names from the first table, then go to the next table until all the tables in that database are done, then move to the next database until all the databases are done, and then move on to the next server. I think I have all the basic pieces, but need help with the sub-queries.

```
--- Drop and recreate the Servers_To_Catalog table if it exists.
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Servers_To_Catalog]') AND TYPE IN (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Servers_To_Catalog]
go

CREATE TABLE dbo.Servers_To_Catalog (ServerName nvarchar(50), Comment nvarchar(200));
GO

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- Populate the Servers_To_Catalog table from an Excel sheet or manually below
Insert Into Servers_To_Catalog (ServerName) values ('CESDBS_OLD')
Insert Into Servers_To_Catalog (ServerName) values ('CESDBS')
Insert Into Servers_To_Catalog (ServerName) values ('DBS2000')
Insert Into Servers_To_Catalog (ServerName) values ('CESOES')
Insert Into Servers_To_Catalog (ServerName) values ('CESROUTE')
Insert Into Servers_To_Catalog (ServerName) values ('CESBS')
Insert Into Servers_To_Catalog (ServerName) values ('WHDBS')
Insert Into Servers_To_Catalog (ServerName) values ('CESDATA')

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- Drop and recreate the temporary Database_Locations table if it exists.
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Database_Locations]') AND TYPE IN (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Database_Locations]
go

CREATE TABLE dbo.Database_Locations (ServerName nvarchar(50), DBName nvarchar(50), TableName nvarchar(50), ColumnName nvarchar(50));
GO

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- Bring in the server names from the Servers_To_Catalog table as @SName.
DECLARE @SName NVARCHAR(50)
SELECT @SName = ServerName
From dbo.Servers_To_Catalog


--- Bring in the names of the databases on a given server as @DName, excluding system databases.
DECLARE @DName NVARCHAR (50)
SELECT @DName = NAME
From sys.databases
WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')

--- Bring in the names of the tables for a given database as @TName
DECLARE @TName NVARCHAR(50) 
SELECT @TName = NAME
FROM sys.Tables


--- Use @TName to get the list of columns
Declare @CName NVarchar(50)
SELECT @CNAME = NAME
From syscolumns
Where id = object_id(@TName)

---Write row to Database_Locations table
Insert into dev.dbo.Database_Locations (ServerName, DBName, TableName, ColumnName)  Select @SName, @DName, @TName, @CName
```

Comment: Arghh. The formatting got pasted all screwy. I hope you can follow it.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: What is the problem? What do you want to achieve (and I don't mean what your whole system should do, but rather what you want from these concrete queries) and what do you get from queries now? Show initial data (like: I have database A with tables B,C and database A1 with tables B1,C1) and desired result (like: I want to have query that gives me (A,B)(A1,B1)).